# Odoo KeyError: 'set_scrollTop' and 'ir.actions.do_nothing'

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Does these type can't not use in odoo 14?

```
return {"type": "ir.actions.do_nothing"}
return {"type": "set_scrollTop"}
```